# Cannot change brightness in ubuntu 20.04, battery drains too fast

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, brightness, amd-graphics

I recently purchased an HP Omen 15(R7 4800h + RTX 2060). When I installed ubuntu 20.04 I could not change the brightness and also the battery works only for 1-1.5 hours (but works for about 7-8 hours on windows).

I tried various solutions for brightness adjustment but none of them worked (using brightness controller, xrandr) and the rest were for intel integrated graphics card.

I have two questions 1) How to get the brightness to work and 2)how to switch to amd integrated gpu (all the answers were for intel).

Currently powerstat -d 0 gives value around 30-40W.

I can provide more information if required.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem to use an AMD graphics card on linux. AMD doesn't provide any infos about their drivers, so the driver in use is reversed engineered. There are similar (but fixable) problems with Nvdia, but you will not succeed with an AMD graphics card.
There is a project called "bumblebee", which allows you to switch from intel to nvidia - but no equivalent for AMD. I hate to say it, but your GPU is only basically supported in Linux.

If you have a chance to switch the GPU in bios to "intel", the results would be good.